Accessing GraphQL variables within network tab
I am using Graphql Apollo, React, and JS. We have form validation in our backend, when trying to display these errors on screen for better user experience, I cannot seem to find a way to access them. Within my browser console, the error I receive is just 'ApolloError', but within the network tab I can see the error message I'm trying to convey on the frontend. What is an easy way to access it? This is what I currently have as my code. Within 'setAlerts' that is the route to get to the error message if I were able to access the network tab. Thanks
 try {
                const { data } = await addUser({
                    variables: { username, email, password }, 
                })
                if (data.addUser === null) {

                    setAlerts(data.errors[0].message, "inline text-groove-red")
                }
                alert('Account creation successful!')
                Auth.login(data.addUser.token);
                navigate('/login')
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }



Attempted to log 'ApolloError' as well as 'data'. When I log data within my catch block it comes back as not defined.

It's const { data, errors } = await addUser(…) (or const result = await addUser(…); result.errors). Not data.errors.

…that is, if you use errorPolicy: 'all'. If you use try/catch, it's err.graphQLErrors on the ApolloError (but notice there might be other reasons for an exception).

Btw, use console.dir(err) instead of console.error(err) to see all its properties

const { data, errors } = await addUser({
  variables: { username, email, password }, 
  errorPolicy: 'all',
})

allows you to access both, the data as well as the error. If you aren't interested in the data in case there is an error, you can also go with errorPolicy: 'ignore'. In any case, no ApolloError will be thrown anymore.
You can check out the documenation for further details. You can also set up more advanced behavior with an ErrorLink.

It's errors not error
